# Calling function with a '&' in front of the function name

Tags: c, embedded, nxp-microcontroller

I am using the NXP SDK for a project.
The SDK contains several sample codes.
One of this sample is called "lpuart_interrupt".
In this example, the LPUART_GetStatusFlags function is used as following:

```
    /* If new data arrived. */
    if ((kLPUART_RxDataRegFullFlag)&LPUART_GetStatusFlags(DEMO_LPUART))
    {
      ...
```

What I do not understand is why there is a '&' character in front of the function name ?
How the function is supposed to work when it is called in such a way ?

The prototype of the function is as following:

```
    uint32_t LPUART_GetStatusFlags(LPUART_Type *base);
```

kLPUART_RxDataRegFullFlag is part of the following enum :

```
    enum _lpuart_flags
    {
        kLPUART_TxDataRegEmptyFlag = (LPUART_STAT_TDRE_MASK),
        kLPUART_TransmissionCompleteFlag = (LPUART_STAT_TC_MASK),
        kLPUART_RxDataRegFullFlag = (LPUART_STAT_RDRF_MASK),
        ...
    }
```

and LPUART_STAT_RDRF_MASK is defined as following:

```
    #define LPUART_STAT_RDRF_MASK (0x200000U)
```

Comment: `&` here is bitwise AND, you can rewrite it like `LPUART_GetStatusFlags(DEMO_LPUART) & (kLPUART_RxDataRegFullFlag)`

Comment: It might be clearer if we drop the crappy coding style with parenthesis disease: `if (kLPUART_RxDataRegFullFlag & LPUART_GetStatusFlags(DEMO_LPUART))`. Now, if the question is what `flag_register & mask` is supposed to do, then the answer is to study the bitwise operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ampersand is used in this case to invoke the bitwise AND operator between the return value of the `LPUART_GetStatusFlags` function and the constant `LPUART_STAT_RDRF_MASK`.

Using the bitwise AND operator like this is a common way to test whether a specific flag is set.

In your case the value of `kLPUART_RxDataRegFullFlag` is `0x200000` corresponding to the bit pattern `0000 0000 0010 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000`.

So, the bitwise AND operation will evaluate to zero if bit number 22 is NOT set in the 32-bit return value of the `LPUART_GetStatusFlags` function. If it is set, the result will be non-zero and the code protected by the if-clause will be executed.

By introducing a helper function such as this, the intent of the if-clause will be easier to understand.

```
static int RxDataRegisterIsFull(LPUART_Type *const uart)
{
    const uint32_t flags = LPUART_GetStatusFlags(uart);
    const uint32_t mask = kLPUART_RxDataRegFullFlag;
    return (flags & mask) ? 1 : 0;
}

/* If new data arrived. */
if (RxDataRegisterIsFull(DEMO_LPUART))
{
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I got it now. It was mainly the syntax which was not clear for me. The fact that the '&' character is stuck to the function name is very confusing.